# Linq - Value of type 'System.Guid' cannot be converted to 'String'

Tags: sql, vb.net, string, linq

I'm using Linqer to convert SQL to Linq:

```
Update EmployeeSite SET SiteId = Null 
WHERE SiteId = '86086EC5-567A-46B3-8DFC-E624F9B0324B'
```

Gets translated into:

```
Dim queryEmployeeSites = _
    From employeesites In rdc.EmployeeSites _
    Where _
      CStr(employeesites.SiteId) = "86086EC5-567A-46B3-8DFC-E624F9B0324B" _
    Select employeesites
For Each employeesites As EmployeeSite In queryEmployeeSites
    employeesites.SiteId = Nothing
Next
rdc.SubmitChanges()
```

But when I try to run the Linq code I get the error message:

Error Compiling Expression: Error Compiling Expression: Value of type 'System.Guid' cannot be converted to 'String'.

I am very new to Linq. Can someone please explain what is wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim queryEmployeeSites = _
    From employeesites In rdc.EmployeeSites _
    Where _
    employeesites.SiteId.ToString().Equals("86086EC5-567A-46B3-8DFC-E624F9B0324B") _
    Select employeesites

For Each employeesites As EmployeeSite In queryEmployeeSites
    employeesites.SiteId = Nothing
Next

rdc.SubmitChanges()
```

Calling `ToString()` instead should work, also it's better to use `Equals` for String Equality, or use `String.Compare`.

Comment: Why not use the equality operator.  It seems to be overloaded to call Equals anyway and it is more readable to me.

Answer (score 4):

You can replace `CStr(employeesites.SiteId)` with `employeesites.SiteId.ToString()`, but the best is to compare the other way around

```
employeesites.SiteId = Guid.Parse("86086EC5-567A-46B3-8DFC-E624F9B0324B")
```

This way you don't run into issues with different capitalization, etc.